# ejecutar programa de C desde archivo .bat

Tags: c, batch

lo que quiero saber es si se puede ejecutar un programa de C y darle las entradas al programa por medio del mismo archivo .bat por ejemplo un programa que sume 2 numeros lo que hago en el codigo abajo es compilarlo y generar un  .exe que se llama sumar entonces en la siguiente linea lo ejecuta y la hora de ejecutarlo quiero que al pedir los numeros el programa para sumar automaticcamente se introduzcan el 10 luego el 20 y ya el programa diga cuanto es la suma... se puede hacer de alguna manera?
 de ante mano muchas gracias

```
gcc sumar.c -o sumar

sumar

10

20

pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el programa espera recibir los valores a través de la entrada estándar lo que puedes hacer es redirigir dicha entrada a un fichero.

El batch quedaría  así:

```
sumar < entrada.txt
```

Si lo que quieres es proporcionar los valores directamente desde el batch tienes que modificar tu programa para que lea los parámetros de entrada:

batch:

```
sumar 10 20
```

C:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a, b;
  if( argc == 3 )
  {
    a = strtol(argv[1],NULL,10);
    b = strtol(argv[2],NULL,10);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Introduce dos números:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
  }

  printf("El resultado es %d\n",a+b);
}
```

Comment: me podrías  explicar un poco mas la primera opción que me mencionas por favor? 

por que no debo de modificar el programa en C

el progrma en C es:

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int num1,num2,res;
 printf("Escribe un numero\n");
 scanf("%d",&num1);

 printf("Escribe otro numero\n");
 scanf("%d",&num2);
 res=num1+num2;
 printf("El Resultado es %d",res);
 
 return 0;
}

(se ve como todo bien pegado no se como darle formato al codigo)

Comment: @Yept es que los comentarios no son para publicar un programa... en cuanto a lo de la primera opción ese sería el contenido del batch asumiendo que el programa se llama `sumar`